# Pointer arithmetic (pointer substraction with casts)

Tags: c++, c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

Why is the j at the end of the execution an "1"?
Compiled with following flags *gcc -m32 xxx.c* on a 64 bit Unix machine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int  *q = (int *)2;
  char *r = (char *)1;
  int j;

  q++; 
  r++;

  j = (int *)q - (int *)r;

  printf("j = %d\n", j);
  return 0; 
}
```

Code is only for academic purposes! ;)

Comment: Which level of hell does this code come from?

Comment: That's undefined behaviour. To start with, they are not pointers to objects in the same array or pointers to members of the same object.

Comment: @BaummitAugen only for academic purposes ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, in theory this is all undefined behavior, since you are using pointers to not allocated memory, comparing stuff that do not belong to the same array etc.

Now, putting this aside, once you have clear the mechanics of pointer arithmetic it's quite easy:

```
int  *q = (int *)2;
char *r = (char *)1;
int j;
// a pointer is incremented in steps of the size of its "base type"; this
// allows to move to the next element if you are pointing inside an array
q++;   // q=(int*)(2+sizeof(int))=(int *)6
r++;   // r=(char *(1+sizeof(char))=(int *)2;

// again, the difference between two pointers is computed in units of the
// base type; in an array, this gives you how many places are two elements
// apart
j = (int *)q - (int *)r; // (6-2)/sizeof(int)=1
```

(here `sizeof(int)` is 4 since you are compiling with gcc and `-m32`, and `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition of `sizeof`)

Comment: Thank you! This explains it a lot!

Answer (score 1):

> <sub>**Note**: You are invoking undefined behavior, there's nothing saying that the alignment of `int` is `2` or less; nor are `q` and `r` members of the same array, or the same object.. you should never do what you are doing in your snippet.</sub>

---

#### Ignoring the obvious *undefined behavior*

One should never take *undefined behavior* lightly, the result of your code is highly implementation specific, and can do pretty much anything. But theoretically the code will be interpreted as described below, but there is **no** such guarantee.

---

- `j` will be the distance between `q` and `r` (both interpreted as `int*`).
- Incrementing a pointer to `int` will move it `sizeof(int)` bytes forward, while incrementing a pointer to `char` will move it `sizeof(char)` byte forward.
- Subtracting one pointer from another yields the number of *elements* between them, not the number of bytes.

---

#### A few assumptions, and a detailed description

Assuming that the underlying implementation has `sizeof(int) = 4`, we will have the following pseudo-code:

```
int_ptr  q = 2
char_ptr r = 1

/* ++q -> */ value_of(q) += 4;   // sizeof(int) = 4,  value_of(q) = 6
/* ++r -> */ value_of(r) += 1;   // sizeof(char) = 1, value_of(r) = 2

int j = int_ptr(q) - int_ptr(r); // j = 1
                                 // (value_of(q) - value_of(r))/sizeof(int)
```

**The answer**: `j = 1`

Comment: Thank you! This explains it a lot!